# Does Geoserver support WMTS protocol?

Tags: geoserver, wmts

Does Geoserver support WMTS protocol? I find only WMS WFS and WFS-T support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not directly - if you use the [GeoWebCache](https://www.geowebcache.org/) extension (which is built in by default) then you can serve WMTS 1.0.0. and TMS 1.0.0.